# ImageView в android

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Есть ли такой атрибут у imageview, чтобы этот view элемент подстаивался под размеры картинки.

Допустим у нас есть картинка 400x400. Как сделать, так чтобы imageview был такого же размера (автоматически, размеры картинки могут быть неизвестны).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помимо задания wrap_content для высоты и ширины еще стоит добавить свойство [adjustViewBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds).

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`wrap_content` - элемент займёт столько, сколько нужно для картинки.

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Или можете получать размер картинки в пикселях, переводить в `dp` и присваивать длину и ширину программно