# Убрать лишние края в диалоговом окне

Tags: java, android

Есть диалоговое окно, в которое выводятся разные изображения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="190dp">

<ImageView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"


    android:elevation = "2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"

    android:elevation = "2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Поскольку все изображения разных размеров, появляются незаполненные белые края.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их можно убрать? Возможно ли их сделать прозрачными, или есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: wrap_content контейнеру и картинке?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не сработало.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/590052/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо установить в ImageView атрибут:

```
android:scaleType=""
```

Этот атрибут масштабирует картинку в зависимости от размеров ImageView

Cо значениями этого атрибута можно ознакомиться по ссылке :
[scaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)